# iframe doesnt work in IE

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I am building a site for a photographer and i used an iframe to include different pictures in to the site as one long strip of pictures. This works fine in chrome safari en firefox but doesnt seem to work in internet explorer?
**This is the file where I use the iframe**

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/overalheader.php';
include 'includes/aside.php'; 

if (isset($_GET['id']) === true && empty($_GET['id']) === false) {
    $_SESSION['serie_id'] = $_GET['id'];
    $lengte = lengte_frame($_SESSION['serie_id']);
    ?>
    <iframe src="includes/fotos.php" frameborder="0" height="520px" width="<?php echo $lengte; ?>px"></iframe>
    <?php
}
else {
    echo 'hallee dermee';
}
 include 'includes/overall/overalfooter.php';?>
```

**This is the fotos.php file**

```
<?php
include '../core/init.php';

$tekst = get_tekst($_SESSION['serie_id']);
$fotos = get_fotos($_SESSION['serie_id']);
?>


        <div width="135" style="float:left; padding-left:15; border:1; max-width:200"></div>
        <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($fotos as $foto) {
            if ($count == 0) {
                $breed = 160;
            } else {
                $breed = 15;
            }
            echo '<div style="float:left; padding-left:' . $breed . '" width="' . $foto['width'] . '"><img src="../' . $foto['path'] . '" height="' . $foto['height'] . '" width="' . $foto['width'] . '"></div>';
            $count++;
        }

        if (empty($tekst) === false) {
       echo '<table style="float:left; padding-left:15;" width="200"><tr><td valign="top"><font face="Courier New, Courier, monospace" color="#777777" size="2px">' . $tekst . '</font><td><tr></table>';
        } 

        ?>
```

Comment: What's your `Doctype`?  And can you be more specific about what's going wrong?  Does the `iframe` load at all?  Is there an error message?

Comment: try removing frameborder from iframe. Tell if it works @Jaap115

Comment: Instead of the PHP code, could you post the resulting HTML (from within the browser, right click and "View Source")? It's not that I can't read PHP, but I don't have the include files you mention, so I can't test.

Comment: in IE I get a line in stead of the pictures

Comment: As an aside, you know `isset($_GET['id']) === true && empty($_GET['id']) === false` is just the same as `isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])`? (And I guess you might be able to drop the check for `isset` altogether, but I've not used PHP in a while.)

Comment: ok i tried to remove the frameborder but it didnt work and i tried to remove the px in the height but i also didnt do the trick

Comment: the site is www.romitweebeeke.com

Comment: The width on the iframe on that site is "9891" pixels. Are you sure you mean that? Could it be that IE doesn't like widths as large as that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be what you are setting for the height of those images.

Looking at the source in other browsers, the pictures (IMG tags) are showing the height attribute as empty. In IE the height for all the images is showing up with a value of 1.

This PHP variable:

```
$foto['height']
```

... has an invalid value stored in it.

This doesn't seem to be an IFRAME problem but rather with the images inside it.

Comment: oke that makes sense but why id that only with IE and not with the other browsers

Comment: Different browsers respond differently to errors. If you see browsers behaving differently, chances are high that it's caused by an error on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `height="520px"` for an attribute, which is not correct. Size attributes must *always* be a single number, in pixels.
So the correct thing to do would be `height="520"` (and ditto for the width). Or, use styles.

Comment: no that didnt do it. I keep seeing the one line but when i click different links the line chanches as if it loads the other photo's